# Data on 4G only with 3g access without data

Tags: mobile-data, internet, 3g, 4g

My provider has special 4G only bundles at more GB/$ but has no VoLTE support, I was looking for a solution to block mobile data when and after i get a call or for other reasons when I drop to 3G/H+. It opens the taps on my balance when it sits on H+ and i have only one solution for now is to block out my calls which isn't a very  great solution. any help to this is highly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You can try to automate the process. But root access will be required for the automation app(s).